# Jquery Validator not working properly on a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a dropdown it is validating but its option value are also turning red when a validation error is shown.Like in the image color is also shown in Red but i don't want to change its color.

[image]

```
jQuery("#frm").validate({
            rules: {
                color: 'required',
                ...
            },
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: How are you applying the color to the error message ? Please show us that code as well.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping: In my case error class is get appended to dropdown when validation error gets fired that's why it is turning to red, Can u please give solution for that.

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin only applies/removes classes.  This validation plugin does not include any CSS, so any issues with style/color are solely due to your CSS rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [highlight](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) method in your jQuery `validate` to ensure that the `errorClass` is not getting applied towards the `select` option as well.

Add this code in your `jQuery` **validate** after the `messages`

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
   $(element).removeClass(errorClass); //prevent class to be added to selects
},
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('#frm').validate({
  errorClass: "my_error",
  rules: {
    color: 'required'
  },
  messages: {
    someSelect: "Required *"
  },
  highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass); //prevent class to be added to selects
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

```css
.my_error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="frm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="color">
      <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```